# How to change the @Table name value dynamically in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have table Name **Users**. Example as follows.

```
@Data
@Entiity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class Users{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String Address;
    private float salary;
    private String state;
}
```

Now I want to split this table with respect to the state.

---Arizona Users---

Users_AZ
All users from Arizona state will be in Users_AZ Table.
---California Users---

Users_CA
All users from California state will be in Users_CA Table.

Attributes for all the table will be same but the name of the table will be different.
I don't want to create different model class for all the state as the attribute is same.
How can I dynamically change the table value at runtime?

I'm unable to find any solution for this

Comment: you need create a second entity that represent your second table, or you  must have one table Users with a column state that represent which state

Comment: You already have a `state` property. What's the actual need you have? Sorting by it is not particularly expensive...

Comment: Data per state will be more than 20 Million. If I were to store all state data in single table it would cross 1 Billion. Using filter on a Billion data in MySQL will be expensive I think

Comment: Have you made sure that you are using Sql indexing on `state`?

Comment: Apart from the 20Million data per state, new data is coming every 5sec. So Indexing might not be appropriate for this approach

Comment: You can use JPA inheritance, `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)` strategy, using runtime polymorphism you can create object & save accordingly, if you are okay with this, however you will need multiple entity classes to be created.